# How to generate function call in Visual Studio from known C# function in [CSharp]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-generation

Where are code located for Visual Studio 2017/19 for refactor operations like

- Introduce Constant
- Change Signature
- Rename method

Refactor operation in VS2019:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/refactoring-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Can I locate code and recompile it for my instance of Visual Studio?

I want to make new command, when Given existing function like

```
 private void Call(int v1, int v2, string v3, int v4, int v5) {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

I can generate code which calls this function

```
int v1 = default(int);
int v2 = default(int);
string v3 = default(string);
int v4 = default(int);
int v5 = default(int);

Call(v1: v1, v2: v2, v3: v3, v4: v4, v5: v5);
```

Comment: you question is kind of hard to understand but if i get you right you are looking to override an existing function you can do like this `override private void Call(int v1, int v2, string v3, int v4, int v5)`

Comment: Refactor operations, are bulbs or screws pictures appearing in Visual Studio for selected code , you can click and REFACTOR selected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write your own functions for generating/modifying code, you want Roslyn syntax transformation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-transformation

In short:

> - Install the *.NET Compiler Platform SDK*
> - Create a new C# **Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool** project. In Visual Studio, right-click the `SyntaxTransformationQuickStart` solution node. Choose **Add > New Project** to display the *New Project* dialog. Under **Visual C# > Extensibility**, choose **Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool**.
> - Create and transform trees